# Which serial port does linux kernel use for console?

Tags: linux, serial-port, u-boot

When I boot my embedded linux system I see uboot messages through a serial test cable, but no messages after the “Starting kernel…” message. The system does successfully boot after about one minute. [Based on "Problem #1" at this post](https://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Kernel_-_Common_Problems_Booting_Linux) I believe that the kernel has probably been configured to use a console port different than the port uboot is using. But the solution described at that post seems to require access to kernel build configuration files, which I don't have. How can I find which port the kernel uses for console output? Physical access to the port is difficult - can I find the information somewhere in /etc?
Thanks!

Comment: *"But the solution described at that post..."* -- You have misidentified your problem and possible solution.  You actually have that article's **Problem #2** (but with silent uncompression, a build option), and therefore should suspect **Cause #1**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/proc/consoles` will show you what devices are used for the system console. See the [Linux Kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/proc.html#proc-consoles) documentation for details. Below is sample output from my system.

```
/ # cat /proc/consoles
ttyS0                -W- (EC p a)    4:64
/ #
```

You can also look at `/proc/cmdline` to see what arguments were given to the Kernel when it was loaded (e.g. from u-boot). Below is some sample output.

```
/ # cat /proc/cmdline
console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk root=/dev/mmcblk1p3 rootwait
/ #
```